# typescript create type with static key and variable number of dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, dynamic, types, typeerror

I have a TypeScript object that contains both a known static key and an unknown number of dynamic keys. At a given point in time the object can look like this:

```
{
    created: 32323232,
    'https://gbhgr.com/bhtgttg/bffgth': <Observable1>,
    'https://trhhhtgrhgr.com/bgbtebg/byrf': <Observable2>,
    'https://domain4.com/ngfbgb/frogf': <Observable4>
}
```

I can't figure out how to type this. The type I came up with:

```
type Cache = {
  created: number,
  [key:string]?: Observable<HttpResponse<any>>
}
```

gives Typescript errors on the line

```
 [key:string]?: Observable<HttpResponse<any>>
```

on ? (there can be 0,n number of keys so it's optional, therefore the ?):

```
';' expected.ts(1005)
Property or signature expected.ts(1131)
```

on Observable:

```
(method) Observable<HttpResponse>(): any
'Observable', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010)
```

on HttpResponse:

```
(type parameter) HttpResponse in Observable<HttpResponse>(): any
'HttpResponse' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
'Observable', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010)
```

on any:

```
(type parameter) any in <any>(): any
'any' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Call signature, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7020)
Type parameter name cannot be 'any'.ts(2368)
```

What do the errors mean? How can I do this?

typescript version: "~4.3.2"

Comment: Your code has a bunch of errors and it's not clear that it makes sense for an answer to go through each one.  You don't need (and can't write) a `?` on an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures); they already accept any number of keys including zero.  The other errors probably clear up once you remove the `?`.  Your fundamental problem is going to be that you cannot have the dynamic props be one type and the static props be of an incompatible type.

Comment: If you update your TS version you can use a template literal pattern index signature so that any key that starts with `"http"` will be of the `Observable<Blah<Blarg>>` type you want and `created` will be a `number`, like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/w16EkN) (but it's important for your question code to include a [mre] with no external dependencies you don't have as tags).

Comment: ... so my type should be 

type Cache = {
  [key:string]: Observable<HttpResponse<any>> | number
}

saying 'this type accepts any key with a return value of Observer or a number...'

Comment: @jcalz '...you cannot have the dynamic props be one type and the static props be of an incompatible type.'. Didn't know that. Thanx for pointing out the (obvious) ? error and the example.

Comment: Yes, the union is one way of doing that.  For that and other approaches, see the answer to the linked question.